# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] not working correctly

Tags: php, redirect

I have file logout.php which contains following:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();  
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
?>
```

It's all working correctly, sessions are destroyed and the page is redirected to index.php. I want simple message there, something like: "Logout was succesful" written only if redirected from logout page.

But here is the problem:
In index.php I have following temporary script:

```
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];}
```

It should be logout.php, because I was redirected from that page. But for unknown reason, it says "localhost/index.php". And if I hit "back" button, it really redirect me to index.php, not logout.php. Where is the problem?

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is passed to your web server from the browser so because you sent a `header('Location...` redirect from logout.php the web browser doesn't register it as a page which the user actually visited so they were ultimately referred from the place which they clicked the button `index.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not set a "flash" session? E.g.

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
$_SESSION['logout'] = true;
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
```

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['logout'])) {
    echo "Logout was successful";
    unset($_SESSION['logout']);
}
```

Comment: Great stuff! could you mark this as answered please in that case :)